# Implicit declaration of function error

Tags: c, linux, ubuntu, linux-kernel

While compiling code for softiwarp using this [guide](http://www.reflectionsofthevoid.com/2011/03/how-to-install-soft-iwarp-on-ubuntu.html) 
I encountered the following errors while compile codes in kernel directory.

```
error: implicit declaration of function ‘remap_vmalloc_range’
error: implicit declaration of function ‘vmalloc’
error: implicit declaration of function ‘vmalloc_user’ 
error: implicit declaration of function ‘vfree’
```

Anyone here could help guide me, how to install the libraries related to this function? I'm using ubuntu 16.04.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

These functions are declared in [`<linux/vmalloc.h>`](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/include/linux/vmalloc.h). You need to `#include` that header.

Comment: Hi a3f, Thanks for the fast reply, this did resolve my issue. Could share which directory should I look for in case I came across similar errors for other libraries not included error?

Comment: Searching for the function usually helps.